# Find maximum value of one column based on group_by multiple other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, data-cleaning

I have the a table of the following form in R:

```
| COUNTRY | date_start | code  | bin | ord |
| -----------------------------------------|
| Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 4.5.1 | 1   |  3  |
| Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 4.5.2 | 1   |  0  |   
| Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 4.4.1 | 1   |  2  |
| Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 4.4.2 | 0   |  1  |
| Norway  | 25/02/2021 | 4.4.2 | 0   |  1  |
```

First I want to drop the column 'who_code', and then I want to create an extra column 'ordMax', and populate it  with the maximum value of the 'ord' column for a given 'COUNTRY' and 'date_start'. So in this example the new column would be

```
| COUNTRY | date_start | bin | ord | ordMax |
| ------------------------------------------|
| Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 1   |  3  |    3   |
| Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 1   |  0  |    3   |   
| Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 1   |  2  |    2   |
| Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 0   |  1  |    2   |
| Norway  | 25/02/2021 | 0   |  1  |    1   |
```

I have tried a couple of methods in R, using both 'aggregate' and the dplyr library, but it nothing seemed to work. One of the things that I tried was:

```
df_k_reduced <- df_k %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY, date_start) %>%
  select(-code) %>%
  summarise(ordMax = max(ord))
```

But this gives something like:

```
    | COUNTRY | date_start | ordMax |
    | ------------------------------|
    | Chile   | 04/11/2020 |    3   |   
    | Norway  | 23/02/2021 |    2   |
    | Norway  | 25/02/2021 |    1   |
```

Note that 'bin' and the original 'ord' column have also been dropped, even though that was not the original intention.

How would I obtain the table with that extra column, where the only dropped column is 'code', and no rows are dropped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `slice_max` instead of `summarise` to return all the columns after the `select` step

```
library(dplyr)
df_k %>%
  group_by(COUNTRY, date_start) %>%
  select(-code) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = 'ord', n = 1)
```

If we need to create a new column, use `mutate`

```
df_k %>%
    group_by(COUNTRY, date_start) %>%
    select(-code) %>%
    mutate(ordMax = max(ord, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: What that method does is to replace the existing 'ord' column with maximum values. Is it possible to keep the original 'ord' column, while putting those maximum values in a new column?

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` way

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("COUNTRY | date_start | code  | bin | ord
  Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 4.5.1 | 1   |  3  
   Chile   | 04/11/2020 | 4.5.2 | 1   |  0     
   Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 4.4.1 | 1   |  2  
   Norway  | 23/02/2021 | 4.4.2 | 0   |  1  
   Norway  | 25/02/2021 | 4.4.2 | 0   |  1  ")
```

**code**

```
DT[, ordMax := max(ord), by = .(COUNTRY, date_start)][, code := NULL][]
```

**output**

```
#    COUNTRY date_start bin ord ordMax
# 1:   Chile 04/11/2020   1   3      3
# 2:   Chile 04/11/2020   1   0      3
# 3:  Norway 23/02/2021   1   2      2
# 4:  Norway 23/02/2021   0   1      2
# 5:  Norway 25/02/2021   0   1      1
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. I should also add that my original table is actually much larger, and is an existing dataframe (which for these purposes I shall call 'df_k'). I tried DT <- fread(df_k), but get an error message. What would be the equivalent to read an existing dataframe? Error message: input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r

Comment: `data.table::setDT(df_k)`

Comment: so `library(data.table);setDT(df_k)[, ordMax := max(ord), by = .(COUNTRY, date_start)][, code := NULL][]` should work fine.. (NB: this permanently changes your df_k-data!)

Comment: for conversion back to data.frame, use `setDF()`

Comment: Yes, that has done it. Thanks. So basically, I used    DT <- data.table::setDT(df_k)      followed by      DT[, ordMax := max(ord), by = .(COUNTRY, date_start)][, code := NULL][]